# url parameters missing after adding a comment and redirecting back to blog post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, url-routing

I am teaching myself asp .net mvc3 by creating a blog application. However, I have
problems with comment upload. It is a very subtle error in that everything works when a user leaves a comment. However, the url of the post changes.

So, a blog post has a url

```
http://localhost:49175/Blog/Details/3/Third-post
```

This is generated by the url route map here:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "BlogDetail", // Route name
                "Blog/Details/{id}/{urlHeader}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, urlHeader = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Now, when a user leaves a comment - he is directed to a comment controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(BlogDetailsViewModels viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try 
            {
                blogrepository.Add(viewModel.Comment);
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Blog", new { id = viewModel.Comment.BlogID });
            }
            catch (DataException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save comment. Try again, and if the problem persits then contact administrator.");
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Blog", new { id = viewModel.Comment.BlogID });
    }
}
```

However, when somebody leaves a comment - he is redirected back to

```
http://localhost:49175/Blog/Details/3
```

I know, as of now there is nothing in the RedirectToAction that passes the urlHeader info. However, I have tried a few things like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Blog", new { id = viewModel.Comment.BlogID, urlHeader = viewModel.Blog.UrlHeader });
```

However, it doesn´t seem to work.

This is the blog details controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Blog/Details/5
    public ViewResult Details(int id, string urlHeader)
    {
        var blogs = blogrepository.GetBlog(id);
        var recentblogs = blogrepository.FindRecentBlogs(5);
        var archivelist = blogrepository.ArchiveList();
        BlogDetailsViewModels viewModel = new BlogDetailsViewModels { Blog = blogs, RecentBlogs = recentblogs, ArchiveList = archivelist };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I am stuck for days on this.

-- Full route method as requested --

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BlogDetail", // Route name
            "Blog/Details/{id}/{urlHeader}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, urlHeader = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BlogArchive", // Route name
            "Blog/{year}/{month}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Archive" }, // Parameter defaults
            new { year = @"\d{4}", month = @"\d{1,2}", } // Parameter constraints
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your full route setup in Global.asax? Do you have some other routes setup?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, is this route "Blog/Details/{id}/{urlHeader}" working when you hit its example on browser address bar directly?

Comment: yes, it works .. I just tried it now

Comment: changed a few things ... I am getting an error "object set to instance of object" for _urlHeader. But _id is working fine. Any ideas, the variables are: 
var _id = viewModel.Comment.BlogID;
var _urlHeader = viewModel.Blog.UrlHeader;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form does not contains data for viewModel.Blog.UrlHeader, it will be an empty string, even viewModel.Blog may be null.

You can add a parameter to your post action method, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BlogDetailsViewModels viewModel, String urlHeader)
```

And, in your view that renders the form, use this code to generate the form element:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Create","Blog",new{urlHeader=Model.Blog.UrlHeader})
```

***Alternatively***, you can add a hidden input in your form for the urlHeader. In this way, you don't have to do any of previous two updates.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Blog.UrlHeader)
```

Either way, make sure your Model.Blog.UrlHeader is not null or an empty string